# Moving Collapsible Hamburger Icon to right justified

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently taking Angela Yu's Beginner Web Dev. course. She is using Bootstrap 4 in the tutorials, however, Bootstrap 5 is the current version nowadays which is significantly different.

In the skeleton HTML she is having us use, her hamburger bar is right justified when the viewport is sized down to mobile. However, because of the Bootstrap version difference, I just can't seem to find out how to move it to the right side like hers, mine won't move from the left justification.

[Here's the current version vs. where I would like it to be placed (right justified)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYrZI.png)

```
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
      <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" href="#">Tindog</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Content</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I tried ms-auto and ml-auto. I also tried messing with justify-content-end class on collapse menu. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't sure whether you wanted the links to also be on the left side or not, so how about this?

I added

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
```

around the links to make the text aligned to the right side.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Tindog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-qKXV1j0HvMUeCBQ+QVp7JcfGl760yU08IQ+GpUo5hlbpg51QRiuqHAJz8+BrxE/N" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: How would I go about justifying right the links as well?

Comment: I edited my answer to justify the links to the right side.